# How to send props to class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to send props to my class component. So in the parent component:

```
<Child contract={_contract}/>
```

I sent the props like this.

And in child component in one of my functions, I am calling the prop like this:

```
    class Mint extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      balance: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await axios.get(`https://api.cronoscan.com/api?module=stats&action=tokensupply&contractaddress=${ADDRESS}&apikey=${apikey}`)
      .then(output => {
        this.setState({
          balance: output.data.result
        })
      })
  }

  mintNft = async () => { 
    var _mintAmount = Number(document.querySelector("[name=amount]").value); 
    var mintRate = Number(await this.props.contract.methods.cost().call()); 
    var totalAmount = mintRate * _mintAmount; 
    this.props.contract.methods.mint(
      localStorage
        .getItem('walletAddress'), _mintAmount)
        .send({
           from: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('walletAddress')),
           value: String(totalAmount)
        });
  }

  render() {
    const { balance } = this.state;
    const { nftdata } = this.state;
    return (
                      <button onClick={mintNft}>Mint</button>
    );
  }
}

export default Mint;
```

but it gives an error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')

Waiting for your answers. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest looking into switching from class components to functional if at all possible. Class components are basically unsupported now, and not receiving further updates or fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Please change it

```
async function func() { 
  var mintRate = Number(await this.props.contract.methods.cost().call()); 
};
```

To

```
const func = async () => { 
  var mintRate = Number(await this.props.contract.methods.cost().call()); 
};
```

To understand this change, you need to understand the difference between Arrow Functions & General Functions. Please check https://betterprogramming.pub/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256

Codesandbox Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-snow-234or7

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I didnt solve my issue

Comment: Which error you are getting now?

Comment: the same: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')

Comment: please provide the child component code.

Comment: I shared the full code

Comment: mintNft is called in the React component? because this can not be accessible in outside functions.

Comment: I shared one example, please check also

Comment: this time I am getting error like this: 'mintNft' is not defined  no-undef because I am calling it inside the render

Comment: call mintNft in your componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

If `mintNft` is meant to be called within the `Mint` component ***and*** access `Mint`'s props, it should be declared in scope. Move the `mintNft` callback into the component's scope so it can access the `this` of the `Mint` component and have a defined `this.props` object.

```
class Mint extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      balance: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await axios.get(`https://api.cronoscan.com/api?module=stats&action=tokensupply&contractaddress=${ADDRESS}&apikey=${apikey}`)
      .then(output => {
        this.setState({
          balance: output.data.result
        })
      })
  }

  mintNft = async () => { 
    var _mintAmount = Number(document.querySelector("[name=amount]").value); 
    var mintRate = Number(await this.props.contract.methods.cost().call()); 
    var totalAmount = mintRate * _mintAmount; 
    this.props.contract.methods.mint(
      localStorage
        .getItem('walletAddress'), _mintAmount)
        .send({
           from: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('walletAddress')),
           value: String(totalAmount)
        });
  }

  ...

  render() {
    const { balance, nftdata } = this.state;
    return (
      <button onClick={this.mintNft}> // <-- pass as callback
        Mint
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I fully shared my code according to your answer but I am getting 'mintNft' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @eysan That is because it's a class method, i.e. try `<button onClick={this.mintNft}>Mint</button>`. I've updated my answer to include your new code.

Comment: @eysan Have you made this additional change and tested?